# Csv feed (columns change order)

Tags: php, import-from-csv

I have a script to get the yahoo stock data and all works fine (well kind of or I wouldn't be here!)

- when I get "goog" the name is in row "ab" and the symbol is in row "ag"
- when I get "yhoo" the name is in row "ac" and the symbol is in row "ah"

This is causing my data to be all messed up, can anyone please help,

My script uses a class and then each value is given a name using a foreach loop, eg:

```
foreach( $objStock->getQuotes() as $code => $stock)
{
   $symbol = str_replace('"', "", $stock[32]);
   $name = str_replace('"', "", $stock[27]);
```

Example link to get the CSV (just change the "goog" to "yhoo" to get the different tables

http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=goog&f=abc1e7jj1j5k5m5m8op2r7s7t7w1a2b6dee8gkj6lm3m6npp5rr5st1t8v7w4a5b3cc6d1e9hg5i5j4k1k4l1mm4m7p6r6vwxe1&e=.csv

Comment: And how are we supposed to know how `$objStock` is built? And what does the `getQuotes` method do? Point is: we need way more information than what you provided to be able to help.

Comment: sorry dont know how to post a pull page of code, please view code here: http://hdpixeldesign.com/1.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your CSV parsing is bugged. How about using [str_getcsv](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) ?

Comment: any help would be appreciated, i am what they call stuck lol: http://hdpixeldesign.com/1.html

Comment: modify your `getQuotes` method. Instead of using `explode`, `foreach` - use `str_getcsv`.

Comment: just looking into the str_getcsv now